# Number of Trees with n Nodes

Tags: trees

I am struggling with a question that asks the number of trees that exist with x nodes and max level z. During my research I found that the number of binary trees with x nodes can be obtained by Catalan numbers. However, there is this element of max levels z. I don't know how that affects the problem. Can anyone provide me any guidance as to how to solve this problem? I obviously do not want a solution. I am trying to understand what is being asked so that I can solve it.

Comment: Since you mention levels, these must be rooted trees. Are they binary trees, as suggested by your comment, or rooted trees in general?

Comment: I believe it is referring to binary tree's.

Comment: You should probably try to count the number of trees with at least $z+1$ levels and $x$ nodes.

Comment: http://www-math.mit.edu/~djk/18.310/18.310F04/counting_trees.html

Answer (score 10):

This is not a solution, or even a useful hint, but perhaps these comments will be useful to someone.

Let $t(n,h)$ be the number of binary trees of height $h$ having $n$ nodes; if I understand correctly, you’re to find some sort of usable expression for $t(n,h)$. That appears to me to be a very hard problem.

A few results are easy: $t(h+1,h)=2^h$, $t(n,h)\ne 0$ iff $h<n<2^{h+1}$, $t(2^{h+1}-1,h)=1$, and of course $\sum_h t(n,h)=C_n$, the $n$-th Catalan number. Summing in the other direction, $\sum_n t(n,h)$ is the $h$-th term of [OEIS A001699](http://oeis.org/A001699), for which the OEIS entry mentions no closed form. Here’s a table of $t(n,h)$ for $1\le n\le 8$ and $0\le h\le 7$:

$$\begin{array}{l|cccccccc|c}
n\backslash h&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&\text{Total}\\ \hline
0&1&&&&&&&&1\\
1&1&&&&&&&&1\\
2&0&2&&&&&&&2\\
3&0&1&4&&&&&&5\\
4&0&0&6&8&&&&&14\\
5&0&0&6&20&16&&&&42\\
6&0&0&4&40&56&32&&&132\\
7&0&0&1&68&152&144&64&&429\\
8&0&0&0&94&376&480&352&128&1430
\end{array}$$

An analysis like the one that leads to the Catalan recurrence for binary trees on $n$ nodes yields a very messy recurrence for $t(n,h)$:

$$t(n+1,h+1)=2\sum_{k=h+1}^nt(k,h)\sum_{i=0}^{h-1}t(n-k,i)+\sum_{k=h+1}^{n-h-1}t(k,h)t(n-k,h)\;.\tag{1}$$

Without the factor of $2$, the double summation counts the number of ways of building a binary tree on $n+1$ vertices whose left subtree has height $h$ and whose right subtree has height less than $h$; doubling this adds the trees whose right subtrees have height $h$ and whose left subtrees have height less than $h$. The last term on the right counts the binary trees on $n+1$ vertices whose left and right subtrees both have height $h$.

$(1)$ does reduce to something reasonable in special cases. For example, it’s easily verified that

$$t(h+2,h)=2\Big(t(h,h-1)+t(h+1,h-1)\Big)$$

for $h\ge 2$.

This is messy enough, however, that I can’t help wondering whether this is the right problem. By the way, it doesn’t appear to help to replace *of height h* with *of height at most h*: that just replaces the entries in the table above with cumulative row sums, which don’t appear to be any nicer.

**Added:** $(1)$ requires that $t(0,0)=1$ and that the empty tree have height $0$. I’ve added a row to the table to reflect this.

Gerry Myerson has found [OEIS A073429](http://oeis.org/A073429) and [OEIS A073345](http://oeis.org/A073345), which are versions of the table above. Unfortunately, it appears that not much more is known.

Comment: Through $n=6$, your table agrees with http://oeis.org/A073429, but then the numbers diverge. I wonder whether there isn't a mistake somewhere. See also http://oeis.org/A073345.

Comment: @Gerry: I miscalculated $t(7,3)$; the other divergences were knock-on effect. Thanks very much: somehow I missed [OEIS A073429](http://oeis.org/A073429) and [OEIS A073345](http://oeis.org/A073345), despite their being exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I'm tempted to +1 even for the amount of work you put into the matrix and all the symbols in your answer. :)