# How many pure trees with a fixed number of nodes exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, trees

How many pure trees of size (number of nodes) $n$ exist?
Apart from having this fixed size, the trees can be arbitrary.

The sequence starts like this:

Here's the beginning of the sequence:

[image: 1 1 2 5]

Comment: Have a look at this related post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169155/number-of-trees-with-n-nodes?rq=1

Comment: This is the catalan numebers, [OEIS A000108](http://oeis.org/A000108)

Comment: Dear closevoters: that related post is not a duplicate (it's being asked by someone who already knows about Catalan numbers and is looking for a generalization).

Comment: Catalan numbers seems to be right - although I'm confused because the related question claims they are just for the binary trees.